# Error importing googleanalytics on Python 3.8

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-import, google-analytics-api

`pip install googleanalytics`
and
`pip3 install googleanalytics`

both work fine, but

```
import googleanalytics
```

returns:

optional_warn_function.func_name = f.func_name
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall the package using the following comment.

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/dvska/gdata-python3#egg=gdata
```

Or use `f.__name__` instead of `f.func_name` in the code.

For more information, see  https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/29